# Progressive web app is not working on android

Tags: wordpress, progressive-web-apps

I have made a progressive web app using wordpress plugin. But it is not working in my phone.. The theme which i have used is not shown in android and add to home screen pop-up mini-info bar is not coming.. please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You need to be more specific when asking questions. Think about the situation of a person trying to answer you. First do some research yourself. Then give a snippet of the code you think that should be working and it is not. Be more specific. Your question is too vague and general. Good luck!

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.